# Reactstrap Dropdown unable to capture data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do a dropdown where I can choose a car and block out days. So far I am able to choose the car, and have days disabled. However, when I hit the button, the data is not being captured.

I have tried checking through a console log. and I am able to capture data, but it just doesn't translate on the main function

Here is part of my code in a modal form.

Appreciate any help on this. Thanks

```
const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);
const [isOpenCars, setIsOpenCars] = useState(false);

const [car, setCar] = useState("");
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("http://localhost:4000/admin/cars")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      setCars(res);
    });
}, []);
```

```
const handleChooseCar = (indivCar) => {
  setCar(indivCar);
  const dates = [];
  props.bookings.forEach((indivBooking) => {
    if (indivBooking.car._id === indivCar._id) {
      dates.push({
        start: indivBooking.startDate,
        end: indivBooking.endDate,
      });
    }
  });
  setBlockedDates(dates);
};

const handleChooseDates = (day, modifiers = {}) => {
  if (modifiers.disabled) {
    return;
  }
  const range = DateUtils.addDayToRange(day, dateRange);
  setDateRange(range);
};
const { from, to } = dateRange;
const modifiers = { start: from, end: to };

const disabledDays = [{ before: new Date() }];

blockedDates.forEach((indivDates) => {
  disabledDays.push({
    after: new Date(indivDates.start),
    before: new Date(indivDates.end),
  });
});
```

```
<FormGroup>
  <Label>Car:</Label>
  <Dropdown
    isOpen={isOpenCars}
    toggle={() => setIsOpenCars(!isOpenCars)}
  >
    <DropdownToggle caret>
      {!car ? "Choose a car" : car.model}
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
      {cars.map((indivCar) => (
        <DropdownItem
          key={indivCar._id}
          onClick={() => handleChooseCar(indivCar)}
        >
          {indivCar.make} {indivCar.model}
        </DropdownItem>
      ))}
    </DropdownMenu>
  </Dropdown>
</FormGroup>
```

```
<Button
  style={{ backgroundColor: "seagreen" }}
  onClick={() =>
    handleSaveCar(
      car
    )
  }
>
  {isEditing ? "Edit Booking" : "Complete Booking"} 
</Button>
```

Comment: It'd help if you stitched together these snippets of code. Is all of this inside of the same component? Also, can you elaborate on what you mean by "the data is not being captured?" Do you mean the `car` variable being passed into `handleSaveCar` is not what's expected?

Comment: Thank you. I apologize for getting back later. I have solved the issue. Thank you for your willingness to help :)